# Concurrency with Windows FileIO

Tags: c#, sqlite, file-io, concurrency, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a Windows Store app that retrieves some information from the server and display it locally. To increase the "responsiveness" of the app, I decided to store the query results in local app data storage. Before a request is submitted, it will check the local store for saved response and display that first. I considered 2 options SQLite and normal file I/O and I chose the latter. While I was implementing it, I found that there may be cases when the same file is being read and written at the same time. I am using FileIO class, more specifically the WriteTextAsync and ReadTextAsync methods. Does FileIO help us handle concurrent reading and writing to the same file, like blocking reading while reading is being performed?

By the way will it be faster if I use SQLite instead of FileIO? And does SQLite handle this case well?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is counter productivity to used concurrency with file IO, because of the spinning nature of harddrives, unless you have RAID. So concurrent read/write definitely will slow down the performance. However, it is good idea to separate file IO calls from the UI thread, by asynchronously calling file IO api.

Please be aware that UI component is not thread safe, so you need to synchronize the return of the file IO thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be more troublesome to implement with FileIO so I think I'd better change to sqlite.

Comment: I may be wrong, but sqlite being a filesystem DB, you'll probably end up with the same issue.